# Tomcat irresponsive

Tags: apache, tomcat, ajp

We have configured Apache and Tomcat using AJP connector:

In Apache log we found there is a long response time (for all request between some time period) , tomcat has received request but some how response not delivered to Apache, there is no error or exception in tomcat log.

In Apache log we found:

```
"AH01012: ajp_handle_cping_cpong: ajp_ilink_receive failed"
```

There is no log for action in tomcat access log.

What could be the reason?

Comment: are you using oracle as database?

Answer (score 0):

1) Increase the thread count
2) configure "org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProtocol" instead of APR in Tomcat.
3) If you are using Oracle jdbc classes12.jar then replace it with ojdbc14.
4) Add connectionTimeout and keepAliveTimeout to your AJP connector found in $TOMCAT_HOME/conf/server.xml.
5) This is httpd-mpm.conf file that holds values provided in your comments. Keep all but change this part:

```
<IfModule mpm_worker_module> 
    StartServers 2 
    #this was 150 before 
    MaxClients 500 
    MinSpareThreads 25 
    MaxSpareThreads 75 
    ThreadsPerChild 1000 
    MaxRequestsPerChild 0 
</IfModule>
```

I changed **`ThreadsPerChild 25`**  to **`ThreadsPerChild 1000`**

Comment: We have configured max thread = 200.
Already AjpProtocol is configured.
We are using sqljdbc4.jar

Comment: plx post /etc/log/httpd/ log to trace more information about the error

Comment: in httpd.conf :-
<Proxy balancer://tomcat_4_7_cluster>
 BalancerMember ajp://yogeshr.local.com:10004 route=collaborate_4 timeout=120 ping=30 retry=60
 BalancerMember ajp://yogeshr.local.com:10007 route=collaborate_7 timeout=120 ping=30 retry=60
</Proxy>

And in server.xml in tomcat :
<Connector port="10001" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443" URIEncoding="UTF-8"/>

Comment: <IfModule mpm_prefork_module>
    StartServers          5
    MinSpareServers       5
    MaxSpareServers      10
    MaxClients          150
    MaxRequestsPerChild   0
</IfModule>
<IfModule mpm_worker_module>
    StartServers          2
 #this was 150 before
    MaxClients          500
    MinSpareThreads      25
    MaxSpareThreads      75 
    ThreadsPerChild      25
    MaxRequestsPerChild   0
</IfModule>
<IfModule mpm_beos_module>
    StartThreads            10
    MaxClients              50
    MaxRequestsPerThread 10000
</IfModule>

Comment: @YogeshPatel is my answer helped you? waiting for your reply and please don't forget to vote up and mark answer if that helped you